# Assign NDOF button action

Tags: customization, keymap, 3d-mouse

In Blender 3.6.0 under Ubuntu 22.04 I'm trying to configure my SpaceMouse Compact buttons.
In the configuration panel I first tried to emulate a keypress:

[image]

but in Blender it has no effect. Then I restored back to the button behavior and configured a new key assignment in preferences:

[image]

[image]

But still pressing the MouseSpace button does nothing.
What should I do in order to use my buttons?

Comment: Blender 3.6 isn't even in beta yet so you'll have to ask the developers that one!

Comment: Does it change so much just for a key assign?

Comment: No idea. If it works in 3.4.1 (the current released version) I'd report it as a bug via the Help > Report a Bug menu in Blender.

Comment: Seems like device driver issue, not a bug in Blender. Even if it was a bug in Blender, one could set up the device's driver to activate some keyboard combo that you normally don't use like Ctrl+Shift+Alt+] and then use a regular hotkey set to that in Blender.

Comment: True. That's why I wondered if it worked in 3.4.1.

Comment: @JohnEason I installed v3.4.1 and it does not work either. In the keymap preferences window, if I click on the "type of event" field, Blender says "press a key". I click my button and it recognize it as "NDOF Button 2". Hence the device driver is fine.

Comment: As I said you should report it as a bug.